# Return a selected status table and then join a count of those statuses from another table. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I am selected all the status from a status table and then would like to add a new column with the count of those statuses. zero should be the default if nothing was found.

```
SELECT
    AQA.StatusId,
    AQA.[Description],
    NULL(Count(AQ.ActiveStatus)) AS Count
FROM
    AP_QuoteActiveStatus AS AQA WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AP_Quote AS AQ WITH(NOLOCK) ON AQ.ActiveStatus = AQA.StatusId
ORDER BY AQA.[Description]
```

The errors i get read as:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near 'Count'. Msg
>   319, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon. Msg 319, Level 15,
>   State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this
>   statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a
>   change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be
>   terminated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    AQA.StatusId,
    AQA.[Description],
    Count(ISNULL(AQ.ActiveStatus, '0')) AS [Count]
FROM
    AP_QuoteActiveStatus AS AQA WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN AP_Quote AS AQ WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON AQ.ActiveStatus = AQA.StatusId
GROUP BY AQA.StatusId, AQA.[Description]
ORDER BY AQA.[Description]
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Was it the Grouped by that removed duplicates of the outer join?

Comment: Yes, the `GROUP BY` is doing that in this case.

Comment: Thanks, and since the default return of a count would be 0, i did not need the NULL(Count(AQ.ActiveStatus),'0')?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you were trying to do. In TSQL, there is no `NULL` function - I believe you are looking for either `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`. You can certainly include that in your query - I updated my answer for you.

Comment: Yup that's the one i was trying to do.